# How to manually install vboxdrv?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I remove the vboxdrv while encountering the virtualbox problem and I didn't find a way to get the vboxdrv back. So how do i make it install or add again?

Answer (score 1):

`vboxdrv` is part of the package `virtualbox-dkms`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

The `--reinstall` option will remove the package (but not the packages that depend on it), then re-install the package.